# BitConvert.IsLittleEndianon on different endian architectures

Tags: c#, bitconverter

The documentation of BitConverter.IsLittleEndian says:

> Indicates the byte order ("endianness") in which data is stored in **this** computer architecture.

"this" is confusing me. Say I have the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian);
```

Now say I go to compile my program on my little endian machine. If I copy paste the executable onto a big endian machine, will it say false? or true? Basically I want to know if the field is a dynamic one, and if the JIT has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` indicates the architecture of the machine your binary is running on, *not* the one you're compiling on.  It's checked entirely at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! Runtime evaluation were the words I was looking for!